# What does the Malbim in his perush on אשת חיל in Mishlei, base his derech hamuskal on?

Tags: commentaries, aishes-chayil

The Malbim in his perush on אשת חיל in Mishlei chapter 31,has 2 Perushim and one is called derech hamuskal. He learns that the whole Eishes Chayil is a Mashal.
Where is the Malbim coming from, what source?
Is the Malbim basing the Mashal on a chaza"l somewhere or otherwise what license does the Malbim have to explain this way, can we learn it as a mashal for something else then?

Comment: Could you please provide a link to the text you are quoting or place an exact and complete quote of the Malbim you have a question about.

Comment: Do we even _have_ Chazal's explanation for most of Nach?  I'm aware of a few midrashim, and of course scattered citations in the Gemara, but nothing like a comprehensive peirush.  It's either come up with your own chiddushim or don't learn [large parts of] Nach.

Comment: Perhaps he knows something we don’t. Something hidden.